# QtWebsocket / JWebsocket large data issue

Tags: android, c++, qt, websocket

I'm using a c++ app with a QtWebsocket server, and a JWebsocket client on an android app.

When I send a large string (png files as 64 based string), I only receive 1400 characters, have you got any idea why ?

Maybe I missed something, I read that I could send large data because the websocket implementation internally split them.
So maybe I missed something in the client..

Server side :

```
void WebSocketServer::sendImage(cv::Mat image)
{
    QtWebsocket::QWsSocket* client;
    uchar* datas = image.data;
    std::cout << image.cols * image.rows << std::endl;
    std::cout << "coucou" << std::endl;
    QString dataString;
    for (int i = 0; i < (image.cols * image.rows ) - 2 ; i++)
    {
        dataString += datas[i];

    }
    qDebug() << dataString;
    std::cout << "Sending an image" << std::endl;
    cv::Mat dst;
    cv::cvtColor(image, dst, CV_BGR2RGB);
    QImage imageAsQImage((uchar*)dst.data, dst.cols, dst.rows, QImage::Format_RGB32);


    QString encodedImage = encodeToBase64(imageAsQImage);

    foreach(client, clients)
    {
        client->write(encodedImage);
        //client->write(dataString);
    }
}
```

Client side :

```
public class WebSocketClient extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Long> implements WebSocketClientTokenListener{

private BaseTokenClient btc;


public WebSocketClient() {
System.out.println("Creating a new websocket client");
btc = new BaseTokenClient();
btc.addListener(this);
btc.addListener(new RpcListener());
Rpc.setDefaultBaseTokenClient(btc);
Rrpc.setDefaultBaseTokenClient(btc);
}
...

    @Override
public void processPacket(WebSocketClientEvent arg0, WebSocketPacket arg1) {
if(arg0.getClient().getNegotiatedEncoding() == WebSocketEncoding.TEXT)
{
    // here is only the first 1400 chars...
    String response = arg1.getASCII();
}

}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS @Kurt Pattyn said, I was reading a packet which was not the complete message.
I asked to Antoine Lafarge (QtWebsocket founder) and he confirmed that the issue was on the client side (jWebSocket).

How did I solve it :
I did not find any clear informations about reading frames with jWebSocket, so I changed the lib to this one :
https://github.com/koush/android-websockets

Now I correctly retrieve my full image as a 64 encoded string

Answer (score 1):

You are reading a packet which is not the complete message. As you mentioned yourself, WebSockets splits a data stream into smaller packets (frames).

Comment: Does that means that the packet should contains all the frames ? (And I should just find a way to iterate over them)
Or that i should receive multiple packets ? (I only receive one)

The jwebsocket documentations seems very odd to me..
Thanks